# Problem with numba vectorize: array cannot be represented as numpy type

Tags: python, numpy, numba

The basic problem I am getting is the following:

```
In [39]: import numba as nb

In [40]: import numpy as np

In [41]: mat = np.array([[1.2, 1.6, 0.5, 0  ],
    ...:                 [1.2, 1.6, 0,   0.5]])

In [42]: @nb.vectorize
    ...: def f(a, b, c, d):
    ...:     load = np.array([a, b, c, d])
    ...:     return mat @ load
    ...:

In [43]: f(1.1, 2.1, 3, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<SNIP>
NotImplementedError: array(float64, 1d, C) cannot be represented as a Numpy dtype
```

Side note: in this example, `mat` represents a matrix of load factors (to be multiplied by a set of loads) and never changes; in my actual problem I am dynamically generating many such `mat`s and dynamically generating dozens of these factored load combination functions (each with its own constant `mat` value).

Now, obviously this function is more readily implemented as a basic matrix multiplication operation, without bothering with numba:

```
In [44]: def f(a, b, c, d):
    ...:     load = np.array([a, b, c, d])
    ...:     return mat @ load
    ...:

In [45]: f(1.1, 2.1, 3, 4)
Out[45]: array([6.18, 6.68])
```

However my goal in using numba is to allow arguments of various shapes of arrays to be broadcasted together, and not just atomic values. Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> c = 1
>>> d = 2
>>> f(a, b, c, d)
# expected output:
array([[[ 3.3,  3.8],
        [ 6.1,  6.6],
        [ 8.9,  9.4]],

       [[ 8.1,  8.6],
        [10.9, 11.4],
        [13.7, 14.2]]])
```

How can I vectorize an operation that results in a numpy array for every operation, and return a nested matrix of the results matching the broadcasted shapes of the inputs?

EDIT:

By the way I am not very opinionated about the output shape. Maybe it would be more convenient for the output to be shaped like this?

```
>>> f(a, b, c, d)
# expected output:
array([[[ 3.3,  6.1,  8.9],
        [ 8.1, 10.9, 13.7]],

       [[ 3.8,  6.6,  9.4],
        [ 8.6, 11.4, 14.2]]])
```

EDIT:

Here is the best attempt I've been able to make using `nb.guvectorize`. It gives a performance warning, and the wrong result.

```
In [97]: @nb.guvectorize(["f8, f8, f8, f8, f8[:,:], f8[::1]"], "(), (), (), (), (n,m)-> (n)")
    ...: def f(a, b, c, d, mat, res):
    ...:     for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
    ...:         res[i] = mat[i] @ np.array([a, b, c, d])
    ...:
<ipython-input-97-9dea8a9aed86>:4: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, C))
  res[i] = mat[i] @ np.array([a, b, c, d])
<SNIP>

In [98]: f(a, b, c, d, mat)
Out[98]:
array([[[ 3.3,  3.3],
        [ 6.1,  6.1],
        [ 8.9,  8.9]],

       [[ 8.1,  8.1],
        [10.9, 10.9],
        [13.7, 13.7]]])
```

Comment: Adding as a comment because I don't want to derail the question: I think the correct tool for this is probably going to be `nb.guvectorize`. But even after reading [the documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) I just don't know how to use it properly. If someone agrees it is the correct tool I look forward to their solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to vectorize each row of `mat` one at a time. This would require creating a separate vectorized function for each row, and also doing away with matrix multiplication operation in favor of basic arithmetic. It would look something like this:

```
# note that `mat` is of this form:
"""
        a    b    c    d
array([[1.2, 1.6, 0.5, 0. ],
       [1.2, 1.6, 0. , 0.5]])
"""

# So we create two functions to perform the matrix multiplication operation of each row separately, f_c and f_d:

@nb.vectorize
def f_c(a, b, c):
    """Load factor for d is zero."""
    return 1.2*a + 1.6*b + 0.5*c


@nb.vectorize
def f_d(a, b, d):
    """Load factor for c is zero."""
    return 1.2*a + 1.6*b + 0.5*d


# now call both functions and pack the results into a matrix:


def f(a, b, c, d):
    return np.array([f_c(a, b, c), f_d(a, b, d)])
```

This works. The timing appears to be pretty good, too (it would be better if it was jit-ed with `@nb.njit`, but this breaks broadcasting):

```
In [94]: %timeit f(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1)
2.7 µs ± 9.58 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Compare this to the simple matrix-multiplication version:

```
def g(a, b, c, d):
    return mat @ np.array([a, b, c, d])
```

...which is almost exactly twice as fast:

```
In [98]: %timeit g(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1)
1.34 µs ± 1.84 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

...but this version doesn't work for broadcasting arrays.

In order to support broadcasting, paying a cost of 2x slowdown isn't too awful I suppose; at least it isn't 10x. However, I do not like the idea that I have to both create a bunch of compiled functions and do away with fast matrix multiplication. This "multiple function" approach also doesn't try to take advantage of parallel processing.

Here is another implementation using guvectorize that seems much more straightforward than the method above, but it is slower and produces a performance warning:

```
In [69]: @nb.guvectorize(["f8, f8, f8, f8, f8[:,:], f8[::1]"], "(), (), (), (), (m,n) -> (m)")
    ...: def f(a, b, c, d, m, res):
    ...:     res[:] = m @ np.array([a, b, c, d])
    ...: 
<ipython-input-69-fe24a895fcf3>:3: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, A), array(float64, 1d, C))
  res[:] = m @ np.array([a, b, c, d])
<SNIP>

In [70]: %timeit f(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, mat)
14.5 µs ± 93.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

There has to be a better way.